# How to create proper JMeter workload model

Tags: jmeter

How to create proper workload model in JMeter if I have only number of concurrent users and response time as input/requirement? Do I need any additional information in order to load test app?
If these are only info I can get, how to approach load testing in context of using JMeter as load testing tool, any ideas - suggestions - advices?

Answer (score 0):

A "proper workload" would be simulating real life usage of the system under test by "the number of concurrent users".

Just replicate real user behaviour at HTTP protocol level paying attention to pretty much everything i.e.

1. JMeter's network footprint must be exact replica of the browser's network footprint when it comes to [HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) so cross-check the number and the nature of the requests from [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and JMeter's [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener
2. Make sure to send the same/proper [HTTP Headers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
3. As a subset of point 2 pay attention to [Cookies](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
4. Make sure to download [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) like browser does
5. In addition to point 4 make sure to properly handle [cache](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
6. Use [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) wisely to simulate [think times](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time)
7. If your users are doing different actions [configure your JMeter test to distribute them](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) like real users are distributed

Once done just run your test with the anticipated amount of users for the desired duration and compare the real response time against the anticipated

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not completely sure what do you mean with point 1. Also, should I use Little's Law as starting point in model creation or there are other/better ways? Btw, I created few models in JMeter, but when I add more virtual users, response time skyrocket so I'm probably doing something wrong or I need to fix some parameters like Throughput, bit since I don't have any relevant inputs except VU and response time that's why I'm struggling how to approach the problem and create realistic load testing plan.

Answer (score 0):

The Avg RT and other KPIs (such as Throughput) are the **result** of generating or executing the workload with a determined # of VUsers. IMO, the best approach is to generate the load by varying the VUsers as shown in the graph:
[image]

This graph also shows a key concept: perfomance (as measure by KPIs) is **not linear** (although it might appear linear at a small # of VUsers).